# Rest WebService C# content length Issue when deployed in DMZ server

Tags: asp.net, rest, web-hosting, dmz

I have application which uses a Rest Service C# which accepts less request content length when in DMZ server.
But the same Service in without DMZ accepts proper request and provides proper response.

Comment: Unfortunately, unsure what anyone outside your specific environment can provide. A quick guess would be to check your DMZ/WAF settings/rules.

Comment: Thank you.Please can you help me with what Kind of Setting should I look in DMZ.?We also have a Firewall layer,is it the problem?

Comment: Can't really guess further for you. Figure out whats "missing" in your (expected) data, and go from there.